# Shortcut to add multiple breakpoints in chrome?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

As in consider I have 100 lines of code & I want breakpoint on every single line, Is there something like click the first line scroll down to 100th line & use shift-click or control-click to select all the lines in between to apply breakpoint ?

Comment: Why you need stop on every single line?
You can write in your code string with one word **debugger** and browser automatically will stop on it.

Comment: In order to understand the flow of my code...If I don't use breakpoints & use "step over to next function call" button it jumps into the jQuery/ember etc libraries that I have used

Answer (score 0):

In chrome you can try to use the `debug` keyword.

```
function debug(fn) { [Command Line API] }
```

For example, paste this code into the Chrome developer console:

```
function hw() { 
    alert('hello world'); 
}

debug (hw);
hw();
```

It will create a virtual file and start with a breakpoint at your function.